# Specify Cheffile to ChefSpec Server Runner

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chefspec

I'm trying to add some unit tests for a cookbook of mine (say cookbook1) with `ChefSpec::ServerRunner`.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
mycookbooks  
    ->cookbook1    
          ->->recipes  
          ->->spec            
    ->cookbook2  
    -> Cheffile
```

I have added   `require 'chefspec/librarian'`  to resolve the dependency cookbooks but this assumes that Cheffile is in the same directory cookbook1.

Is there a way I can specify the path of the Cheffile to 
`ChefSpec::ServerRunner`.

Comment: Yes, the cheffile is supposed to be in the root of your cookbook_path directory. So set cookbook_path to mycookbooks. [see here](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec#configuration)

Comment: `config.cookbook_path = 'path to mycookbooks folder'` , this is how I have tried to configure the cookbook path ( used both the relative and absolute path for this.) when I run `rspec` I get the following error.   `/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/dsl/receiver.rb:30:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /path/to/cookbook1/Cheffile (Errno::ENOENT)`

Answer (score 0):

Call `Dir.chdir` before creating the runner object. The relevant code in ChefSpec is [here](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec/blob/master/lib/chefspec/librarian.rb#L27) and you can see it uses `Dir.pwd` to initialize Librarian.